# Avoid log4j-to-slf4j to download automatically

Tags: java, maven

I have a project where log4j-to-slf4j-2.17.1.jar is automatically downloading as a part of dependency. I have added the exclusions tag as well. But still maven is downloading it.

To note that, I have specified the log4j2 version in the properties tag of the pom.xml. And it is downloading log4j-api-2.17.1.jar(which is expected) as well log4j-to-slf4j-2.17.1.jar(which is not required).

Any work arounds to resolve this? Please note that, I have checked to see that the jar is not available in classpath as well.

**Exclusion in pom.xml**:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-to-slf4j</artifactId>
            <version>2.17.1</version>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

**Classpath**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<classpath>
    <classpathentry kind="src" output="target/classes" path="src/main/java">
        <attributes>
            <attribute name="optional" value="true"/>
            <attribute name="maven.pomderived" value="true"/>
        </attributes>
    </classpathentry>
    <classpathentry excluding="**" kind="src" output="target/classes" path="src/main/resources">
        <attributes>
            <attribute name="maven.pomderived" value="true"/>
        </attributes>
    </classpathentry>
    <classpathentry kind="src" output="target/test-classes" path="src/test/java">
        <attributes>
            <attribute name="optional" value="true"/>
            <attribute name="maven.pomderived" value="true"/>
            <attribute name="test" value="true"/>
        </attributes>
    </classpathentry>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER/org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.launcher.StandardVMType/JavaSE-1.8">
        <attributes>
            <attribute name="maven.pomderived" value="true"/>
        </attributes>
    </classpathentry>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.m2e.MAVEN2_CLASSPATH_CONTAINER">
        <attributes>
            <attribute name="maven.pomderived" value="true"/>
        </attributes>
    </classpathentry>
    <classpathentry kind="output" path="target/classes"/>
</classpath>
```

Comment: Isn't `dependency.exclusions.exclusion.version` redundant?

Comment: I did go through few documentation and SO answers. I see it being used there. That's the reason I went ahead to use it. You have any other options fluffy?

Comment: hmm, I don't think there is a way to not download it, tbh.

Comment: This described post of pom snippet is simply wrong because an exclusion does not allow a `<version>..</version>` tag...apart from that the log4j-api has no dependency to log4j-to-slf4j so the exclusion does not make any sense at all..Furthermore without the whole dependency tree it is no possible to guess where the dependency is coming from ....

Comment: I did check without the version tag first khmarbaise. Only after confirming that the version didn't version, I just tried luck in adding the version tag as well.

Comment: Adding just without even knowing what to do is simply wrong. The version tag is not allowed and should already gave an error...have you even tried to build your application on plain command line?

Comment: Sorry for that. But the version tag didnt gave any errors. Would have obviously removed it if it had shown errors. And the build is perfect as well. Successful with no errors.

Comment: Btw, I believe this version tag is an off-topic to this subject. Any useful work-arounds to focus and try on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`log4j-api` doesn't depends on `log4j-to-slf4j` so adding exclusion in `log4j-api` don't do anything.

Use `mvn dependency:tree` and check which direct dependency brings `log4j-to-slf4j` as transitive dependency then add exclusion there, also version is not required in exclusion since there will be only one version as dependency to an artifact.

Comment: Makes sense Karthik. Used this command to find the right path.